Non-aristotelian logics for philosophers (references request)
Totally layman in logic and philosophy of logic question here.
I am interested in logics that can handle emotions and beliefs. I can't put it much more crearly than this: In real life, it's possible to love and hate someone at the same time (psychology example!), and it's possible to believe and disbelieve of the same thing at the same time, for example, I believe and disbelieve in the existence of God at the same time. I think that "classical" logic can't help me to reason about emotions and beliefs very well. I've heard there are other "types" of logic, like paraconsistent logic, that allow for more "freedom" than strict classical logic. Any good references for me to learn more about this? I want to "handle" psychology better :) with better logical tools, this is my purpose of learning this. Thank you in advance!

Graham Priest's Non-classical logic

^ this ^ — excellent book!

Did you get the term "non-Aristotelian logic" from a van Vogt science fiction book? I've never heard it anywhere else.

@David Gudeman: From a friend in conversation, but I searched and it's used by Alfred Korzybski.

@Mauro ALLEGRANZA: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

You are welcome. And see Korzybski.

@MauroALLEGRANZA, thanks. I see Korzybski also invented "general semantics" which van Vogt also used in some of his books. He must have been a fan of Korzybski. Or just thought Korzybski's ideas were wild enough for science fiction.
